# Get input language from remote ssh session

Tags: ssh, keyboard-layout, tmux, language

I would like to know if it's possible to get locale/input language/keyboard layout of host machine when connected over ssh?

I'm connecting from my Mac to linux server and run some applications in tmux. And I would like to display current input language in tmux's status bar, so I can see if I have switched to the wrong one.
I'm not sure if it's ever possible, because I switch languages on my Mac and it's just sends specific codes to the terminal.

But probably someone knows how to get current keyboard layout over ssh?

Answer (score 0):

If your OS uses systemd you can use localectl. It changes or shows keyboard and language settings:

```
user@host:/$ localectl status    
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
              LANGUAGE=en_US:en
   VC Keymap: n/a
  X11 Layout: be
   X11 Model: pc105
```

To just get the layout:

```
user@host:/$ localectl status | grep Layout | awk '{print $3}'
be
```